# Why do we declare constants, and is it necessary to make them static?

Tags: java, static, constants, final

I know that constants are those variables whose values cannot be changed, but if no part of the program changes their value, are they still required to be declared `final`? And it also seems that they must be static. Why is that?

Comment: cause it's not belong to an instance, belongs to the class itself, you don't need an instance.

Comment: A simple search could've yielded this from a previous question:<br>[Why constants are static][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093230/why-are-java-constants-declared-static

Comment: @Manny264 oh i'm sorry i did try to search but it probably got buried in the results thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I dont get why people are downvoting this question. It certainly is a newbie question for programmers, but well put and deserves a [elaborate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21780524/3239833).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are actually asking several questions at once which I am trying to answer.

### Why use constants at all?

Constants are used to avoid [magic numbers/strings](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/avoid-using-magic-numbers-and-string-literals-in-your-code/) in your code. If you have a string that appears in several occasions of your code, once you have to change that string you only need to change the constant definition and not every occurrence of the string in your code. Also if a constant is only used once it is often a good thing because of its better visibility.

### The `final` keyword.

Its purpose (at least in this context) is twofold. One is to make it impossible to a programmer to change the value. You might have forgotten that it is a constant. The other is to tell the compiler that the value cannot change at runtime. This can be used to create optimized bytecode (e.g. the constant could be removed and every occurrence replaced by its value by the compiler).

### The `static` keyword.

In Java everything is a Class. And every *Class* can have several instances (*objects*). If you dont mark your constant as `static` then every object has "its own constant". Since you dont want that it makes sense to mark it as static. Static fields (or methods) do exist only once per class (as opposed to once per object of the class).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the compiler optimizes the code by replacing every occurrence of the constant by its value, then declaring it static or not shouldn't make any difference, right? So are constants usually declared static simply on the off chance that the above optimization would not be performed?

Comment: @Pooks Both the `final` and the `static` keyword are used in several contexts. Using `final` alone could be used to specify a object field that cannot be changed, but is not "globally" unique - instead it is different for each object.

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly possible to declare non-static finals:

```
class Employee {
  final String empId;

  public Employee(String empId) { this.empId = empId; }
}
```

In other cases you want the field to be constant across all instances of the class:

```
class Color {
  final static int BLACK = 0xFFFFFF;
}
```

As to why you want to declare them `final` at all instead of just not changing them ever,

- It increases program readability, it tells the reader of program something about its behavior that would otherwise have to be in documentation
- Compiler reminds if you attempt to change it by mistake

Answer (score 3):

Normally when you're going to use a constant value on your code, you declare a final static variable. That prevents you from spreading "**magic values**" around the code, which is not a good practice, for mantainability and legibility reasons.

If you don't declare them **final**, code made by other people (or you, in case you forget your initial intention) may modify the variable.

If you don't declare them **static**, every instance of the class you create will have a copy of it, also you'll have to create an instance to get the value. That's not what you want, usually.

Comment: Actually you don't want an instance of the class to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Because static belongs to class rather than any instance.

When it is `static` single copy shared across  all the instances. Where as `instance` member have the individual copy.

consider you need to increase/decrease game score (`count`),  in each stage (Stage class) of your game.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not strictly necessary, but it's recommended for reasons of memory-efficiency:

If you don't declare your constant as `static` every instance of the class (possibly thousands of them) that is created will keep it's own value of (or at least a reference to) that constant in memory, whereas a `static` member is only kept once per class - and since it's constant anyway, that's sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

We declare constants because we will always need some "magic numbers" that are fixed in the code. Using constants means that they are easier to spot, and that when you change them you will change all of them with a edit.

Imagine that your code defines that your window will show `15` records, and that you will consider people as adults when they are `15` years old. Without constants, changing the size of the windows means that you will have to find the `15` ocurrences, do not miss any, and do not change a `15` that means age by mistake.

The `static` part is because you do not want to instantiate an object to get a data that is not related to a particular instance (that is exactly what `static` means, btw, not only when used for constants).