# How do I define constants in an inner class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code in Java which I want to convert to Kotlin:

```
class RideHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class HistoryItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private static final int TYPE_IN_PROGRESS = 1
        private static final int TYPE_CANCELLED = 2
        private static final int TYPE_FINISHED = 3

        // class methods and properties are written
    }
}
```

I have come up with the following code:

```
class RideHistoryAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private inner class HistoryItemHolder(view: View)
        : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        private companion object {
            private const val TYPE_IN_PROGRESS = 1
            private const val TYPE_CANCELLED = 2
            private const val TYPE_FINISHED = 3

            // class methods and properties are written
        }

    }

}
```

Android Studio is showing a red squiggly under "object" of the line `companion object`, saying:

> Companion object is not allowed here

**Note:** I know I can convert it to non-inner class but I'd prefer keeping it one. I also checked I can't define an interface in an inner class too.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you would like to use inner class?

Comment: @NatigBabayev to avoid passing adapter's properties explicitly (inner class reduces extra calls and maintenance of values).

Comment: Why not to move companion object to parent class then?

Comment: @NatigBabayev yes I could do that but since it is related to the HistoryItemHolder (inner class) and not the RecyclerVIew (parent) it would be wrong by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that it is not possible to add constants in an inner-class (see [my question](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-i-define-constants-in-an-inner-class/14260) on Kotlin forums).

However, there are two ways you can go about (I chose the first):

1. Make `ViewHolder` a **non-inner** class - this means it can no longer access methods/properties of Adapter:

   ```
   public class Adapter {

       public class ViewHolder(private val adapter: Adapter) {

           private companion object {
               private const val TYPE_IN_PROGRESS = 1
               private const val TYPE_CANCELLED = 2
               private const val TYPE_FINISHED = 3
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Define constants in the Adapter:

   ```
   public class Adapter {
       private const val TYPE_IN_PROGRESS = 1
       private const val TYPE_CANCELLED = 2
       private const val TYPE_FINISHED = 3

       public class ViewHolder(private val adapter: Adapter) {
           // ..
       }
   }
   ```

**Note:** do not convert your `const val` to `val` as it will bind it to your class instance (which is bad. [More about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8093375/1276636)).

Comment: the second way here is only working because Adapter is not an inner class, you should get compile error `Const 'val' are only allowed on top level or in objects`

Comment: @BabyishTank absolutely. That's why I wrote, "it is not possible to add constants in an inner-class" at the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

First of all you Java is not valid. If you fix it you get an error: `Inner classes can not have static declarations`

[image: invalid java]

You cant have a companion object in an inner class for the same reason that you can not have [`static` members in an inner class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953530/why-does-java-prohibit-static-fields-in-inner-classes)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html:

> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. **Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.**

(highlight by me)

With the same reasoning it does not make sense to have a quasi-static companion object associated with instance.

**Solutions** (pick one):

1. use `val` (similar to `final`).
2. move the companion object to the enclosing class.
3. make `HistoryItemHolder` not an inner class.

Comment: Thanks. I realize my mistake. I must have written like `public static final int TYPE_IN_PROGRESS = 1;`. Now this is a valid Java code.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't convert Java code ([using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file)) of `public static final` line, instead it converts to `private final` (no static means it binds to the instance of the class and not the class and hence not a good practice).

Comment: If you want to have it `static final` (the equivalent of `const` in a companion-object) you must move the companion object to the outer class for the reason given in my answer. Side note: I think a `private final` field is a good solution. Semantically it is very clear what it means.

Comment: Yes it will work but not an elegant solution ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093230/why-are-java-constants-declared-static)). Making the class non-inner (as suggested by @NatigBabayev) seems to be the only valid solution to the problem. I guess I hit Kotlin's rare limits.

Comment: Good point, that is a third way of solving the problem. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes please add it but also write the downsides for each solution to make it a complete answer.

Comment: I will, when I find time. For the moment it will remain an exercise for the reader ;)